# Half page image on MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a landing page in MUI v5 where half of the page is an image and the second part of the page is a form to login. I want the image and form to always fill the page completely with no scroll.

However, when doing so, it seems that MUI root is always affecting the margin so that the view has a horizontal scroll and there is white space on the left-hand side (See example below - and ignore the silly image):

How the page should look (and what it looks like if I scroll to the right):

[image]

How the page should look when I load it before scrolling:

[image]

I've spent hours trying to edit the CSS and figuring out where this is coming from with no luck. There is probably a better way to format this but I am using Grid and have tried Box with no luck.

My source code looks something like:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid/Grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";

import SomeComponent from "...{some_path}...";
import SomeFormComponent from "...{some_path}...";

const SomeComponent = ({children, title, width}) => {
    return (
        <Grid container disableGutters sx={{height: "100vh", width: "100vw"}}>
            <Grid
                item
                xs={false}
                sm={4}
                md={7}
                sx={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${SomeImage})`,
                    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                    backgroundSize: "cover",
                    backgroundPosition: "center",
                }}
            />
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        my: 8,
                        mx: 4,
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    <SomeFormComponent width={width} title={title}>
                        {children}
                    </SomeFormComponent>
                </Box>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

Also, inspecting the page elements, I've identified the padding and margin come from a class called `css-ayh9c9-MuiGrid-root` which seems to be causing this because if I remove the class from the parent, everything works as expected. However, this is being added by MUI behind the scenes because it is nowhere in my source code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `Box` whenever possible because `Grid` does some funky stuff with margins. In this case you can use the `flex` attribute on the children to get the right proportions. here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rur3t?file=/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found the real problem which was semi-related but your answer and the code were critical in me getting there.

I found that using your code sandbox in my app the space was still there. It came down to me using a `Container` component in my app:


`<Container className="App">{...}</Container>`

Changing this to a `Box` and everything worked as expected and the rest of the pages spacing looked better too! Thank you for the help!